# Changing a header in mobile mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I am using jquery.rd-navbar.js for mobile mode responsiveness. The plugin takes my HTML title and makes it into a mobile-title. I want to make that header title a link back to my home page rather than having it as part of the dropdown menu. I've removed the normal link to the home page in the mobile dropdown.

The plugin:

```
/*
* Author: Evgeniy Gusarov StMechanus (Diversant)
* Under the MIT License
*
* Version: 1.0.1
*
*/


;
(function ($) {

  var settings = {
    cntClass: 'rd-mobilemenu',
    menuClass: 'rd-mobilemenu_ul',
    submenuClass: 'rd-mobilemenu_submenu',
    panelClass: 'rd-mobilepanel',
    toggleClass: 'rd-mobilepanel_toggle',
    titleClass: 'rd-mobilepanel_title'
  },
  lastY, dir;


  var RDMobileMenu = function (element, options) {
    this.options = options;

    this.$source = $(element);
  };

  RDMobileMenu.prototype = {
    init: function () {
      var nav = this;
      nav.createDOM();
      nav.createListeners();
    },

    createDOM: function () {
      var nav = this;

      $('body')
      .append($('<div/>', {
        'class': settings.cntClass
      }).append(nav.createNavDOM()))
      .append($('<div/>', {
        'class': settings.panelClass
      })
      .append($('<button/>', {
        'class': settings.toggleClass
      }).append($('<span/>')))
      .append($('<h2/>', {
        'class': settings.titleClass                        
      }).append($('[data-type="rd-navbar-brand"]').length? $('[data-type="rd-navbar-brand"]').html() : document.title))
      );
    },

    createNavDOM: function () {
      var nav = this;

      var menu = $('<ul>', {'class': settings.menuClass});

      var li = nav.$source.children();
      for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        var o = li[i].children,
        item = null;
        for (var j = 0; j < o.length; j++) {
          if (o[j].tagName) {
            if (!item) {
              item = document.createElement('li');
              if (li[i].className.indexOf('active') > -1) {
                item.className = 'active';
              }
            }

            switch (o[j].tagName.toLowerCase()) {
              case 'a':
              var link = o[j].cloneNode(true);
              item.appendChild(link);
              break;
              case 'ul':
              var submenu = o[j].cloneNode(true);
              submenu.className = settings.submenuClass;
              $(submenu).css({"display": "none"});
              item.appendChild(submenu);
              $(item).find('> a')
              .each(function () {
                $this = $(this);
                $this.addClass('rd-with-ul')
                .append($('<span/>', {class: 'rd-submenu-toggle'}))
                .find('.rd-submenu-toggle')
                .on('click', function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  $this = $(this).parent();

                  if ($this.hasClass('rd-with-ul') && !$this.hasClass('active')) {
                    $('.rd-with-ul').removeClass('active');
                    var submenu = $this.addClass('active').parent().find('.' + settings.submenuClass);
                    submenu.stop().slideDown();
                    $('.' + settings.submenuClass).not(submenu).stop().slideUp();
                  } else {
                    var submenu = $this.removeClass('active').parent().find('.' + settings.submenuClass);
                    submenu.stop().slideUp();
                  }
                });
              });

              break;
              default:
              break;
            }
          }
        }

        if (item) {
          menu.append(item);
        }
      }

      return menu;
    },

    createListeners: function () {
      var nav = this;

      nav.createToggleListener();
      nav.createResizeListener();
    },

    createToggleListener: function () {
      var nav = this,
      type;

      if (nav.isMobile()){
        type = 'touchstart';
      }else{
        type = 'click';
      }

      $('body').delegate('.' + settings.toggleClass, type, function () {
        var o = $('.' + settings.cntClass);
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        if (o.hasClass('active')) {
          $(this).removeClass('active');
          o.removeClass('active');
          $('body').undelegate('*', 'mousewheel', nav.scroll);
          $('body').undelegate('*', 'touchmove', nav.scroll);
          $('body').undelegate('*', 'touchend', nav.touchend);
          $('body').undelegate('*', 'touchstart', nav.close);
          $('body').undelegate('*:not(.' + settings.toggleClass + ' span)', 'click', nav.close);
        } else {
          $(this).addClass('active');
          o.addClass('active');
          $('body').delegate('*', 'mousewheel', nav.scroll);
          $('body').delegate('*', 'touchmove', nav.scroll);
          $('body').delegate('*', 'touchend', nav.touchend);
          $('body').delegate('*', 'touchstart', {type: type}, nav.close);
          $('body').delegate('*:not(.' + settings.toggleClass + ' span)', 'click', {type: type}, nav.close);
        }
      });
    },

    createResizeListener: function () {
      var nav = this;

      $(window).on('resize', function () {
        var o = $('.' + settings.cntClass);

        if (o.css('display') == 'none') {
          o.removeClass('active');
          $('.' + settings.toggleClass).removeClass('active');
          $('body').undelegate('*', 'mousewheel', nav.scroll);
          $('body').undelegate('*', 'touchmove', nav.scroll);
          $('body').undelegate('*', 'touchend', nav.touchend);
          $('body').undelegate('*', 'touchstart', nav.close);
          $('body').undelegate('*:not(.' + settings.toggleClass + ' span)', 'click', nav.close);
        }
      });
    },

    scroll: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var menu = $('.' + settings.menuClass);

      var x = e.originalEvent.targetTouches ? e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX : e.pageX,
      y = e.originalEvent.targetTouches ? e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY : e.pageY;

      if (
        y > menu.offset().top &&
        y < (menu.offset().top + menu.outerHeight()) &&
        x > menu.offset().left &&
        x < (menu.offset().left + menu.outerWidth())
        ) {
        var delta = 0;
      if (e.originalEvent.targetTouches) {
        if (!lastY) lastY = y;
        delta = (lastY - y);

        lastY = y;
        dir = delta > 0;

      } else {
        delta = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail) * (-50)
      }

      menu.stop().scrollTop(menu.scrollTop() + delta);
    }
    return false;
  },

  touchend: function (e) {
    var menu = $('.' + settings.menuClass);

    menu.stop().animate({
      scrollTop: menu.scrollTop() + (dir ? 100 : -100)
    }, 3000, 'easeOutQuint');
    lastY = undefined;
  },

  close: function (e) {
    if (!e.originalEvent) {
      return;
    }

    var menu = $('.' + settings.menuClass);
    var x = e.originalEvent.targetTouches ? e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX : e.pageX,
    y = e.originalEvent.targetTouches ? e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY : e.pageY;

    if (!(
      y > menu.offset().top &&
      y < (menu.offset().top + menu.outerHeight()) &&
      x > menu.offset().left &&
      x < (menu.offset().left + menu.outerWidth())
      )
      ) {
      $('.' + settings.toggleClass).trigger(e.data.type);
  }
},

isMobile: function () {
  return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
}
};

$.fn.rdparallax = function (option) {
  var o = this;

  if (o.length) {
    new RDMobileMenu(o[0]).init();
  }
  return o;
};

window.RDMobilemenu_autoinit = function (selector) {
  var o = $(selector);
  if (o.length) {
    new RDMobileMenu(o[0]).init();
  }
};
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
  RDMobilemenu_autoinit('[data-type="navbar"]');
});
```

I can either adjust the plugin or add my own JS in my main.js file. I just can't seem to figure it out. This is how it appears in the window in mobile mode

```
<h2 class="rd-mobilepanel_title">Title</h2>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the Link directly into the element that is `[data-type="navbar"]`?

Comment: Also a link to the plugin or a jsfiddle example would be really much more helpful.

Comment: Sorry I didn't fiddle it but I think I figured it out. I don't know how to edit this to make it look clean. Sorry

`$('.rd-mobilepanel_title').html("<a href='index.html'><h2 class='rd-mobilepanel_title'>Title</h2><a/>");`